# On mouse enter input field Expand

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I want to expand my input field when i enter my mouse to fill the entry or collapse its original width when i remove my mouse.

My Html Code

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="All India" >
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<input type="text"  id="service" class="form-control" placeholder="What Service Do You Need Today ?">
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#service').click(function() {
         $('#service').css({
         'width': '134%'
         });
});
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilsingh004/q57Lpke5/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi now you can try to **[focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)** and **[blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)**

```
$( "#service" ).focus(function() {
  $('#service').css({ 'width': '134%' });
});

$( "#service" ).blur(function() {
  $('#service').css({ 'width': '100%' });
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q57Lpke5/4/)**

Comment: using $(this) wouldn't be too much when applying the css

Answer (score 3):

You can use JQuery's 'Focus' method:

```
$('#service').on('focus',function() {
    $('#service').css({'width': '134%'});
});
```

Hope this helps.

To Resize on focus in and then focus out:

```
$('#service').on('focusin',function() {
    $('#service').css({'width': '134%'});
});
$('#service').on('focusout',function() {
     $('#service').css({'width': ''});
});
```

Comment: nothing is happen its only increases the width as my code already did

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

```
$('#service').click(function() {
             $('#service').css({
             'width': '134%'
             });
     return:false;

        });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/q57Lpke5/1/)

Comment: when i use this its remains the same means no event occurs in input field

Answer (score 2):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/pjEdqv

Your looking for the hover function right?

```
$( "#service" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).css({'width': '134%'});
  }, function() {
    $( this ).css({'width': '100%'});
  }
);
```

**Edit**

Updated codepen click expands the input to 134% on mouseleave event returns back to normal

```
$( "#service" ).click(
  function() {
    $( this ).css({'width': '134%'});
  }
);
$( "#service" ).mouseout(function() {
    $( this ).css({'width': '100%'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$('#service')
  .on('focusin',function() {
    $(this).width('134%');
  })
  .on('focusout',function() {
     $(this).width('100%');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
$('#service').on('blur',function() { 

         $('#service').css({
         'width': '100%'
         });

    });
```

or

```
$('#service').on('mouseleave',function() {

         $('#service').css({
         'width': '100%'
         });

    });
```